# Open a map direct with Google Maps when clicking a link

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app with several links to maps that i have created in My Maps. 
When i click in the link, a pop-up window appear asking me with what app i want to open the link (to my map), i can choose to open it with a web browser or with Google Maps app.

Is there a way to make Google Maps app open the link direct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First result when Googling `android google maps intent`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents#intent_requests

> Package: Calling setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps") will
>   ensure that the Google Maps app for Android handles the Intent. If the
>   package isn't set, the system will determine which apps can handle the
>   Intent. If multiple apps are available, the user may be asked which
>   app they would like to use.

Comment: Thanks¡¡ That's exactly what i wanted. Do you know how to do that using a button? Is there a posibility of do that by html??

Comment: The thing is that i am making my app with codiqa, in html5.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with codiqa or using HTML5 to create Android apps.  Though I would hope that there's some way to specify Intent properties.